# BIRT report variable is always null when passed going to service

Tags: variables, report, birt

i wanted to pass a dataset row values to report variable just like in this [example](http://the.drunkensailor.org/birt-reporting-engine-populating-a-report-variable-from-the-database/)

Everything works great as expected. I can even print the text in a label using vars["Foo"] as stated in the example. But when I used that vars["Foo"] to datasource property binding like `"http://localhost:8081/someService?fooIdList=" + vars["Foo"]`, fooIdList is always null.

why is that? Is there a way I can pass it going to a service? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough answer because there are many issues involved.

- Firstly, there is a kind of **egg-and-chicken problem**: datasources are built by the birt engine before datasets are processed. Therefore we can't make use of the result of a dataset in property bindings of a datasource.
- **Declaring a dataset in a report does not mean it will be triggered**: in the example you provided, if we don't drag the column "Foo" into the report then "FooDataset" would never run and the report variable would not be initialized.
- This is very important to understand the **execution order**: if we want to populate a report variable from a dataset D1, and make use of it in a Dataset D2, then *D1 must be triggered by the report before D2*: for example we drag a data element from D1 at the beginning of the report, and set the visibility to false.
- You should probably declare your **datasource as "Scripted"** and make use of a scripted dataset to access the service. You can get a nice example of a scripted dataset [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseBIRT/article.html)

I hope it helps.